# No supported platforms were detected to migrate issue with mfpmigrate from mobilefirst 6.3 to 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I tried the migration process of mobilefirst from v6.3 to v8.0. I installed the migration tool. I tried to migrate a sample program in IBM mobilefirst v6.3 to v8.0 using the command mfpmigrate as shown below. Although the input to the command is a v6.3 program, it says that No supported platforms detected.

> D:\MobileFirst>mfpmigrate client --in AdapterBasedAuth\apps\DoubleStepAuth --out
>    MigrationDemo
>   Error: An error occured during execution of command.
>   Error: No supported platforms were detected to migrate

Could you please help me resolve the above mentioned problems.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, as the sample application **AdapterBasedAuthenticationHybridProject** is not coming with any platforms. You need to first add a supported platform using MobileFirst Studio - iOS, Android etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Idan @idan-adar. That's really helpful.